# What is "eid" in the file picker standard URL?

Tags: files, urlhacking

I am trying to figure out the random Id that generates every time when we click attach file on Notes and Attachments. I copied and paste the Id in the URL but it does not resolve to any valid page but ended up with insufficient privileges.

https://mydomain--mydev2--c.cs20.visual.force.com/widg/filepicker_fs.jsp?lktp=015&mode=1&eid=00Yg0000000aN7g&utype=00P&omode=1&otype=2

what is eid in the above URL? Is that belongs to any record? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: Looks like it is EmailTemp id. Couldn't find any docs for this, but 00Y is definitely and EmailTemp keyPrefix.

Comment: Thanks @MariiaIllarionova. Did Salesforce temporarily stores the attachments somewhere until the user clicks Send button? Is it using any temporary objects? It is so, do we have access to it?

Comment: Looks like it does, however, I couldn't see any reference for in in SOAP Salesforce documentation, so I can't tell for sure.